# JS: Adding Functions before their called, how not to recieve a error?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that adds a `skill button` to the game I am creating. One of the things I would like to do at the game start-up is add some of the functions in my INIT object. However, because i'm calling INIT and these functions BEFORE the actual function gets read by javascript, it throws a error. Now I could just leave my code as it, but I don't like my code dangling around. I want it neat and tidy. Is there a way to fix this?

This is the function i'm refering to:

```
 function addSkillButton(object) {
        var button = document.createElement("button");
        var target = dom.el("skillListWrapper");
        button.textContent = object.name;
        button.setAttribute("id", object.name);
        button.setAttribute("class", "selection");

        switch(object.category){
            case "Attack": 
            target.insertBefore(button, target.children[0]);
            break;
            case "Defend": 
            target.insertBefore(button, target.children[1]);
            break;
            case "Healing": 
            target.insertBefore(button, target.children[2]);
            break;
            case "Debuff": 
            target.insertBefore(button, target.children[3]);
            break;
            default:
            console.log("addSkillButton() - Case Statement has switched to default");
        }
    }
```

Then right below this function is this:

```
addSkillButton(strike);
addSkillButton(defend);
addSkillButton(cure);
addSkillButton(debuff);
```

I want to add these 4 functions to my Game.Init Object, so it looks more clean and it represents at the start of the game what 4 buttons will be loaded. However doing this will give me a error. Is there a way around it?

```
game = {
    init: function() {
        // Game.Start 
        // Log the messages to the chatbox and create buttons for users to select avatars.
            logMessage("Select your Avatar.");
            createButton("dwarfButton", "DWARF");
            logMessage("4 Upgrade Points - 0 Skill Points.");
            logMessage("Heavy Armor, More Balance")
            createButton("dwarfButton", "HUMAN");
            logMessage("2 Upgrade Point - 1 Skill Point.");
            logMessage("Low Armor, Medium agility")
            createButton("dwarfButton", "ELF");
            logMessage("0 Upgrade Points - 2 Skill Points.");
            logMessage("No Armor, High agility")


            listBossStats(angel);
            listPlayerStats(nullman);

    addSkillButton(strike);
    addSkillButton(defend);
    addSkillButton(cure);
    addSkillButton(debuff);
    }
```

Comment: wrap in an anon/iife, call the inner function inline, then return the inner

Answer (score 0):

Self-executing functions!  Try wrapping your game assignment statement like this.

```
game = (function (addSkillButton) {
    return { 
        //game object initialization here
    };
})(addSkillButton);
```